# Adding a running sum to a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object as below

```
var mydata=[
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":1,"Pnts":3,"CumPnts":0},      
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":2,"Pnts":1,"CumPnts":0},  
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":3,"Pnts":4,"CumPnts":0},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":1,"Pnts":2,"CumPnts":0},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":2,"Pnts":4,"CumPnts":0},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":3,"Pnts":2,"CumPnts":0},]
```

I want to update the object so that CumPnts contains a running points total for each Club as below

```
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":1,"Pnts":3,"CumPnts":3},  
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":2,"Pnts":1,"CumPnts":4},
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":3,"Pnts":4,"CumPnts":8},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":1,"Pnts":2,"CumPnts":2},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":2,"Pnts":4,"CumPnts":6},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":3,"Pnts":1,"CumPnts":7},]
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: how have you tried to do this?

Comment: well I tried working with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115740/need-help-with-very-simple-running-total-for-javascript

Comment: what's impeding your progress?

Comment: The data originates in mysql which I retrieve into a ASSOC ARRAY using php  by this $resultearray=array();


while ($FixtureTeams=mysqli_fetch_array($FixtureTeamsresult,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

 {

$resultarray[]=$FixtureTeams;

 }

Comment: What Transcendence is trying to point out nicely is that we are happy to help you fix your code but we're reluctant to write code for you.

Comment: the pass it to javascript with   var phpData=<?php echo json_encode($resultarray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;

Comment: my apologies  David and @Transcendence I'll go and get my bad code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that loops through the list and updates it after it's been added.   But I suspect that the events come in one at a time so there could be another function that can look the cumPtns obj and take from that. Here is for the current list.

```
var cumData = {};

var mydata=[
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":1,"Pnts":3,"CumPnts":0},      
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":2,"Pnts":1,"CumPnts":0},  
{"Club":"Blackburn","EventNo":3,"Pnts":4,"CumPnts":0},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":1,"Pnts":2,"CumPnts":0},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":2,"Pnts":4,"CumPnts":0},
{"Club":"Preston","EventNo":3,"Pnts":2,"CumPnts":0}];


function updateMyData() {
 for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
     var item = mydata[i];
     if(cumData[item.Club] == undefined) {
         cumData[item.Club] = {};
         cumData[item.Club] = item.Pnts; 
     } else {
         cumData[item.Club] = cumData[item.Club] + item.Pnts;
     }
    mydata[i].CumPnts = cumData[item.Club];
  };   
    console.log(mydata);
    //if you want to return it you can have this line below.  Otherwise the object is updated so you'll probably want to do something with it once it's updated.   Call back maybe?
    return mydata;
}


updateMyData();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time it encounters a team it adds it to an array and so does with the corresponding cumPnts, so we can keep track of whether we checked a team earlier or not.

```
var tmArr = [];
var cumArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    var elm = mydata[i];
    var club = elm.Club;
    var points = elm.Pnts;
    var idx = tmArr.indexOf(club);
    if(idx > -1) {
        cumArr[idx] += points;
        elm.CumPnts = cumArr[idx];
    }
    else {
        elm.CumPnts = points;
        tmArr[tmArr.length] = club;
        cumArr[cumArr.length] = points;
    }  
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/hek880yu/1/)

Comment: Thank you I've tried your solution , @user2743289 and alfonso's all work.